# How to load custom page-template from different theme preserving header and footer from default theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a Wordpress project which requieres that a custom page template is loaded from a non active theme, but header and footer should be loaded from active theme.

I know there are plugins available for this task but I need to do it programmaticaly inside a custom plugin.

I can write this code in a custom plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do it. In this example, I use a template inside the plugin but this could be done with a theme template as well.

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'change_template' );
function change_template( $page_template )
{
    if (get_the_ID()== 1)
    {
         $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/page-demo.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```

Hope it helps someone!